# When I press submit it keeps loading but nothing happens

Tags: php, html, database

I have created a form for a simple user sing up which I need to connect to my phpadmin database. When I press the submit button the page keeps on loading but doesn't show anything until it gives error because it surpassed the waiting time period. So, it doesn't give me the message that it supposed to give and the data doesn't go to the database.

This is my form code on html:

```
<form action="../PHP/registrar.php" class="formulario" method="POST">
        
        <h1>Registrate</h1>
        <div class="contenedor">

        
        <div class="input-contenedor">
        <i class="fas fa-signature icon"></i>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre:" required>
        </div>
            
        <div class="input-contenedor">
        <i class="fas fa-user icon"></i>         
        <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" required>
        </div>
        
        <div class="input-contenedor">
        <i class="fas fa-key icon"></i> 
        <input type="password" name="contrasena" placeholder="Contraseña:" required>
        </div>
        
        <div class="input-contenedor">
        <i class="fas fa-phone icon"></i>
        <input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono:" required>
        </div>
        
        
       <input type="submit" value="Registrate" class="button">
     <p>Al registrarte, aceptas nuestras Condiciones de uso y Política de privacidad.</p>
     <p>¿Ya tienes una cuenta?<a class="link" href="..\pags\login.html"> Iniciar Sesión</a></p>
</div>
        
    </form>
```

And this is my PHP code:

```
 <?php
 $conectar=mysqli_connect('localhost:8080','root','','forms');
 if(!$conectar){
 echo"Se conectó la base al servidor";}

  $nombre = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nombre');
  $usuario = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'usuario');
  $contrasena = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'contrasena');
  $telefono = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'telefono');

$sql="INSERT INTO registro (Nombre, Telefono, Usuario, Contraseña) 
VALUES('$nombre', '$usuario', '$contrasena', '$telefono')";
$ejecutar= mysqli_query($conectar,$sql);

if(!$ejecutar){

echo"Hubo algún error";
}else{    
echo"Datos Guardados Correctamente<br><a href='index.html'>Volver</a>";
}

?>
```

There's obviously a mistake in the code, I just can't seem to find it.

Comment: For future reference, it might be a good idea to use some sort of prepared statements when working with database input like in your code. There are examples of using prepared statements [on this page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.execute-examples) that might be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your PHP code and found below mistakes:

You have connected database using mysqli `$conectar= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");`

But after that you have selected  DataBase `$base= mysql_select_db('forms');` using MySQL method instead of `mysqli_select_db()` method

Same for you have executed query using  `$ejecutar= mysql_query($sql);` instead of `mysqli_query ()`

Can you please update your code according to mysqli and run your code again.

Comment: It says that mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in on line 8 ($base= mysqli_select_db('forms');
)
And one on line 24(   $ejecutar= mysqli_query($sql);
)

Comment: Please refer mysqli tutorial for more details. https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_select_db.asp

Comment: Mysqli Example :https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysqli/mysqli_select_query.htm